# Does file descriptor performing IO needs processor cycles?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, file-descriptor

I am digging lastly into os etc and I would like to make sure if I understand correctly - if fd performs IO it does need processor cycles, right? How many file descriptors can perform IO operations simultaneously?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Does it do stuff? Yes. And who's doing stuff in a computer? The CPU. So? ---- As to "how many": OS-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

"Does file descriptor performing IO needs processor cycles?"

No. File descriptor does not do I/O. It is just used by OS to do I/O for application program.

The OS do I/O through DMA or Interrupt machanism, both of which need a few processor cycles to handle context switch.